# How to call new Activity on onSlideMenuItemClick with slide animation?

Tags: android, menu, slide, slidingmenu

I am having problem with slidemenu . I am using   [libslidemenu](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu)  library to draw sliding menu.But thing is that I am writing entire code to show different view in single activity . I want to distribute this in different activity. but problem is that I doesn't get able to show new activity with sliding effect. And new Activity is also require switch case code.How should I made my code so that I wouldn't get need to write switch case in each activity and get new activity with sliding effect. Thanks in advane.

Comment: call a different fragment in one activity is better rather than call a different activity from slidemenu in switch case.

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal..you means call fragment instead calling activity.right?

Comment: Can you give example Please..